# Is there a good list of where I can find alchemy ingredients anywhere?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are plenty of lists of alchemy ingredients and their properties, but I'm looking for a list of where I can find specific ingredients.

In particular, I'm trying to find out where I can find Scaly Pholiata

Answer (score 1):

Woodcutter's Camp at Lake Geir, Altar in the Woods at Autumnshade, and there's a spot near Darklight Tower. Look for dead trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a list like that, the strategy guide is a good source. None of the online wiki's I have found so far have location info.

I did a decent amount of Googling, but I didn't find any online sources that were good. The guide isn't that much...like $20 or something and it is VERY useful if you are a completionist like myself.

Comment: Yeah but you can't Ctrl+F a guide..... :)